# How do I get parsed JSON Data into CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionview

I have what appears to be successfully parsed AS3 image links to an array of UIImage named 'smImg'.

I am now trying to append each link as a UIImage to my UICollectionViewCell's imageView (where I added an IBOutlet 'imageView'.) I keep getting the error 'UICollectionViewCell' does not have a member named 'imageView'. Relevant code below.

ViewModel.swift :

```
func imageForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UIImage {
     return smImg[indexPath.row]
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
func configureCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.imageView!.image = viewModel.imageForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) //Error occurs here
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PhotoCell
    configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

PhotoCell.swift

```
class PhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

}

Can someone please help me fix this? Any help is much appreciated, I try not to ask too many questions on here but have been unable to find a solution on my own.

Comment: [UICollectionViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/index.html) does not have a member named "imageView".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method

```
func configureCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.imageView!.image = viewModel.imageForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) //Error occurs here
}
```

is expecting a UICollectionViewCell, you should change it to expect a photo cell since that is what you are sending it.

```
func configureCell(cell: PhotoCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.imageView!.image = viewModel.imageForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) //Error occurs here
}
```

You also need to make sure you're telling the collectionView to use PhotoCell as its cell type. So when you initialize the collection view you need to have a line that looks something like this

```
collectionView.registerClass(PhotoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Reuse Identifier")
```